# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer not recognized on iPhone app running on iPad

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have an iPhone only application that uses a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to implement a custom interactive transition in a UINavigationController. The gesture recognizer is created and added as follows in the viewDidLoad of the UINavigationController subclass:

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer* edgeRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
edgeRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:edgeRecognizer];
```

When the app is run on the iPad, when I attempt to swipe to pop a view controller from the navigation stack, nothing happens in the app and I get the following console output if I start the gesture to the left of where the app window is:

> unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent,
>   _windowServerHitTestWindow: ; layer = >

Does anyone know the reason for this and how/if I can fix this? I can't find anything so far in the documentation indicating that the edge pan gesture should not run in compatibility mode. I am testing in iOS 8.

The gesture does work in the Simulator, but not on devices.

Comment: Hey Darren, did you ever figure out how to get UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to fire for an iPhone app running on iPad? It still doesn't work for me, even in Xcode 12.4 building for iOS 14... Would love to know if you found a workaround! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you create correctly the story board with their view controller and navigation controllers that animation y created by default (Edge Left swipe to unwind). But if it is not your case you can try to use an UnwindSegue or a dismiss function. But I don´t know what does "pan:" method do.

I did it in one of my apps in Ipad and it called the function correctly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *leftEdgeGesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                                          action:@selector(openLeftSideBar)];
    leftEdgeGesture.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
}

- (void)openLeftSideBar
{
    //the code

}
```

in you’re case, in  you can call an Unwind segue to the view controller you wanna roll back or if the view controller you wanna rollback is just behind of the current view controller use a dismiss function like this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have a custom interactive transition implemented for the navigation controller, which is why I have to add my own gesture recognizer to recover the swipe to navigate back behaviour. The pan selector will start or update the interactive transition, but it is never called in this case.